# Having issue with Modals when opened, the right side of the screen moves to the left by 17px

Tags: html, css

In my website, I have a Nav Bar at the top & when I click on a nav bar item and open a modal, the nav bar items on the right move to the left by 17 pixels.  I did an inspect next to the modal that I opened and it shows it automatically added:

```
style="display:block; padding-right: 17px;"

It gets added to the first <div class at the end of the line 
(right after aria-hidden="true")
```

When I close the modal, it goes away?

The entire screen shifts back.

I have spent a week every day trying to figure this out, but I think it's beyond me.

```
<div class="modal animate fade" id="Searchfor" role="dialog" aria- 
    labelledby="CenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm" 
        role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #337AB7; 
             color:#FFF;">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="CenterTitle"><strong>Search For: 
                </strong></h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
                 aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>

         <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="FbVendor">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <input id="chkFbb" type="checkbox" value="Fb 
                           Services" data-toggle="modal" data- 
                           target="#SearchFb"/><label 
                           for="chkFb">&nbspFb Services</label>
                  </td>
               <tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <input id="chkVend" type="checkbox" value="Vend" 
                           data-toggle="modal" data- 
                           target="#SearchVend"/><label 
                           for="chkVend">&nbspVend Services</label>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
                  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will almost certainly be coming from JavaScript. Are you using any frameworks? It looks like you have Bootstrap, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Yes I do have bootstrap. I'm using Atom for structuring and testing.  I have several scripts and numerous css styles, but there too many to post.  So in the modal above when you click one of the check boxes, it launches another modal with more check boxes for selecting many items.  What I notice is when that modal is closed (I have the inspect element opened) it adds a - 447 position on the left and it goes back to normal.

Comment: correction - the -447 position is from the right side, not the left

Comment: So the issue with the -447 position is from when I have the "inspect element" on.... so this is not an issue--- sorry all - my bad.

Comment: I thought I had this figured out, but it is still shifting the right hand side of the screen by 34 px now....   What I have been able to observe is that after Modal is launched the screen shifts from the right side only, 34 px.  Then when I close the modal, it shifts back 17 px and then another 17 px?   Can anyone advise what might be causing this?